# Choosing discrimination threshold from ROC curve, is there a multiple testing issue?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, sensitivity-specificity

When choosing a discrimination threshold from a ROC curve (as nicely explained on [mathematical thinking](http://mathemathinking.com/uncategorized/what-is-an-roc-curve/)) it strikes me that effectively a hypothesis test has been conducted for each point that is plotted on the ROC curve.

Can this lead to multiple testing issues?  Is it possible to calculate p-values for sensitivity/specificity in order to apply Bonferroni correction to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is sampling variation in the ROC curve but thresholding is more about decision theory than hypothesis testing.

When you decide to classify via algorithm, you have to know about relative costs and benefits of various classification rules you can have. It means there must be an loss function involved. ROC curve itself cannot tell these, but it is a tool for decision making.

Comment: How does the ROC curve help with decisions?

Comment: @FrankHarrell it tells something about various tradeoffs.

Comment: Why should someone be interested in tradeoffs when one can make optimal decisions conditioning on full information (X=c) instead of partial information (X>c)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a multiplicity problem involving the estimation of a hard-to-estimate quantity.  So expect different datasets to yield different "thresholds".  But the biggest problems are that (1) the threshold usually doesn't exist because the problem is truly a continuous one and (2) the use of thresholds devoid of utility considerations leads to suboptimal decision making.  Optimum decisions come from probability models and specification of utilities (costs/loss).

Comment: Even once utility (cost of mis-classification) is specified isn't there a multiple testing issue in picking the threshold to use?

Comment: Not at all.  The threshold (action point) is a function of the utility, not something that you search for in the data.